# Eureka in Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, eureka-forms

I'm trying to import Eureka framework into my Swift 3 project. I'm doing it by following this instruction: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#installation, but Xcode asks me to convert the framework from 2.3 to 3. Doesn't Eureka support Swift 3 version or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Here are some pointers about Swift 3 support and Cocoapods version: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/656

Answer (score 0):

If you have the problem while using CocoaPods to import the framework then remember:

> Cocoapods 1.1.0.rc.3 or newer version must be used.

Fix: update your Cocoapods using

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and then do

```
pod update
```